# Azure Dev Ops - Only allow a certain branch to merge to master

Tags: azure-devops

The branch setup for the project I am on would like to enforce the rule that only the dev branch can merge into master.

Is there a way to set this up with branch policies?
If not, is there another alternative?

We are trying to prevent any devs from attempting to merge into master from wrong branches.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there a way to set this up with branch policies? If not, is there
>   another alternative?

Azure Devops doesn't have the option to control which branch can be merged into master, but we can use branch policies as a workaround. Here's my working direction:

**Step1**.Create a simple pipeline (no matter classic or yaml, but classic is more suitable for this scenario) with one Command-line task:

`script:` ThisIsNotDevBranch.exe test

`fail on standard error:` [image]

`condition when run the task:` [image]

Yaml format:

```
steps:

- script: 'ThisIsNotDevBranch.exe test'
  failOnStderr: true
  displayName: 'Command Line Script'
  condition: ne(variables['System.PullRequest.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/dev')
```

**Step2**.Configure `master` branch's [branch policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops), add [build policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#build-validation) with setting below:

[image]

Choose the created pipeline in Step1 as the one to be used in build policy.

**How it works:**

1.Any time I create a Pull request to merge one branch into master, the pipeline created in Step1 will be triggered automatically.

2.I used a command that actually doesn't exist in CMD task, and checked `Fail On Standard Error` checkbox. Then this task will throw error and fail the task, the pipeline if it runs.

3.With [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) in that task, this task will run only when the source branch of PR is dev branch (`refs/heads/dev`).

4.Now if I create a PR to merge branch `testBranch` into master=>the pipeline run=>custom condition=true=>the task will run, then it throws error to fail the pipeline=>then the PR can't be completed (The complete button in PR can't work if the pipeline fails).

Then if I create a PR to merge branch `dev` into master=>the pipeline run=>the condition=false=>the task will skip=>the pipeline succeeds=>we can approve and complete the PR.

**Note:**

1.If you want to set only the dev branch can merge into master, then use `refs/heads/dev` in condition. If it's Dev, use `refs/heads/Dev` instead.

2.The core of this direction is the conditional CMD task, we can replace it with other kind of task. Also, we don't have to create a pipeline to run the task. If you want, just add the conditional task in your existing pipeline. But it needs extra steps to distinguish whether the pipeline is triggered by PR or normal updated source files. So I recommend creating a new simple classic pipeline to do the validation.

**In addition:**

1.Details about [System.PullRequest.SourceBranch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables).

2.Apart from the build policy, you can also try other policies in branch policies to project your master branch. Just like **Krzysztof Madej** said, you can also consider code reviewers option. Making a combination of these policy options is a good choice!

Comment: This works, but given that this is a relatively common requirement, this approach seems overkill.

Comment: What about this scenario: I create a pull request and the pipeline fails because for whatever reason (Let's say I forgot to include a file in the commit). I fix the error and the pipeline runs again. System.PullRequest.SourceBranch is now NULL. How do I fix that?

Comment: I know this is old, and I am probably stupid, but I am failing incredibly hard on step one. I don't see any of these options. When I pick classic, it wants configuration I have no idea of. When I go through yaml I can complete it, but it complains because there's no trigger.